# Stop iOS music player when app starts and resume when exiting

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

I know its possible to stop iOS Music player when my app starts. But is it possible to resume playback of iOS Music player when I exit my app (it's also an audio app) by tapping home button? Is there an API to resume playback of iOS default music app when my app enters background?

I'm expecting a similar functionality to what iOS does when a notification comes. If I'm already playing a song using default Music app, it would fade out and play notification alert sound, and then music would fade in again.

Is there an API to make this happen in our apps?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code in your AppDelegate...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{   
    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("\(#function)::AudioSession not setted")
    }
}
```

For more information about audio categories check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this won't stop already playing music? will it? As per docs it seems , adding this code will make my app's sound mix with already playing sounds.

Comment: You're right. You have to select the Category that fits with your requirements